# How to hide a duplicate value in synonym domain of Maximo

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere, ibm-maximo-worker-insights

I have a requirement where I want to hide a duplicate value from the domain(lookup of the field). For Example there is a synonym domain called status with 2 same values as Active, I want hide one of them to avoid confusion.  How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to this technote from IBM:
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/229865

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the recommendation. I did tried it before but it didn't give expected result. Could you please suggest any other way

Answer (score 0):

You can make a lookup like this:

```
<table id=mylookup mboname="SYNONYMDOMAIN" 
       inputmode="readonly" selectmode="single"
       whereclause="domainid='MYDOMAIN' and SYNONYMDOMAINID in (select max(synonymdomainid) from maximo.synonymdomain where domainid='MYDOMAIN' group by maxvalue)">
...
</table>
```